# Why does (sum $ takeWhile (<10000000) [1..]) use so much memory?

Tags: haskell

This is what I get in the console:

```
ghci> sum $ takeWhile (<10000000) [1..]
49999995000000
(11.96 secs, 2174569400 bytes)
```

That's over 2GB! I would imagine that `sum` can discard whatever it has already summed. How would you write this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're creating ten million `Integer`s, and a lot of list cells. Also, you're running interpreted code, if you ran it through the compiler, that would reduce the allocation somewhat.

The main problem is that the interpreter doesn't optimise at all, so the `sum` uses the lazy variant that builds a **huge** thunk. `sum` discards the part of the list it has consumed just fine, but it replaces it with a thunk to compute the result afterward, so

```
sum [1,2,3,4 ...]
```

becomes

```
(...((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) + ...)
```

afterward. That's not the optimal substitution, since addition of `Integer`s is strict.

At the ghci prompt, you should write

```
Prelude Data.List> foldl' (+) 0 $ takeWhile (< 10000000) [1 .. ]
49999995000000
(1.41 secs, 1443355832 bytes)
```

to fix that. In a compiled (with optimisations, of course) programme, `sum` will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

This looks exactly like what's described at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memory_leak

So the solution here could be `foldl' (+) 0 $ takeWhile (<10000000) [1..]` (which needs `import Data.List`).

There is probably a better solution, since I'm just a Haskell newbie and was curious, too. =^.^=
(**Edit:** please read the first comment below :-P )

Comment: "If you are noticing a space leak while running your code within GHCi, please note that interpreted code behaves differently from compiled code: even when using `seq`." - http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memory_leak