# Memory leak when generating a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, optimization, memory-leaks

The following code computes numerical trees<sup>1</sup> for quantifiers of type `Quant`, which is similar to the type of functions `all` and `any`:

```
treeOfNumbers :: [(Integer, Integer)]
treeOfNumbers =
  [0..] >>= \ row ->
  let 
    inc = [0 .. row]
    dec = reverse inc
  in
  zip dec inc

type Quant = (Integer -> Bool) -> [Integer] -> Bool

check :: Quant -> (Integer, Integer) -> Bool
check q (m,n) =
  q (\ d -> d - m > 0) [1 .. domN]
  where
    domN = m + n

genTree :: Quant -> [(Integer, Integer)]
genTree q =
  filter (check q) treeOfNumbers
```

For example, the value for `take 10 $ genTree all` is

`[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(0,9)]`

This code, however, appears to cause memory leaks. With ghci’s heap limited at 100M, `genTree all` is interrupted around `(0,1600)`. With the limit at 500M, it stops around `(0,3950)`, after having become very slow.

How can this be improved? I have limited experience with Haskell, and can only guess that perhaps my implementation of `treeOfNumbers` is the culprit; `check` works for large values without any problem.

---

<sup>1</sup>See *Computational Semantics with Functional Programming* (Jan van Eijck and Christina Unger), Cambridge University Press, 2010, pp. 157–159.

Comment: Have you tried running it with [profiling enabled](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1/html/users_guide/profiling.html)?  You could see the cost centers and get a better idea for what is causing the memory problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no memory leak here. You're explicitly telling it to hold on to the entire list of tuples by defining it as a top-level constant. Laziness means it won't generate a value until it's needed, but that doesn't help with retaining values. `treeOfNumbers` won't be garbage collected until the garbage collector can prove it'll never be used again. And some rough math suggests that by the time `(0,1600)` appears in the list, it will be holding on to approximately 1,280,000 tuples. That's going to eat a lot of memory.

Comment: +1. Also, [ghci retains any top-level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986296/io-monadic-assign-operator-causing-ghci-to-explode-for-infinite-list/24990602#24990602). You won't see the memory leak in a compiled program (apart from much GC time).

Comment: all the internal names add to the problem too. in my answer I saw that coding without any internal named entities, with only the top-level `treeOfNumbers`, it gets to the 3000 in 35M only.

Answer (score 3):

Don't name your interim entities unless you absolutely have to.

```
treeOfNumbers :: [(Integer, Integer)]
treeOfNumbers = [0..] >>= \ row -> zip [row, row-1 .. 0] [0 .. row]
  = [p | row <- [0..], p <- zip [row, row-1 .. 0] [0 .. row]]

type Quant = (Integer -> Bool) -> [Integer] -> Bool

check :: Quant -> (Integer, Integer) -> Bool
check q (m,n) = q (> m) [1 .. m + n] 

genTree :: Quant -> [(Integer, Integer)]
genTree q = filter (check q) treeOfNumbers
  = [ p | p <- [p | row <- [0..], p <- zip [row, row-1 .. 0] [0 .. row]]
        , check q p]
  = [ p | row <- [0..], p <- zip [row, row-1 .. 0] [0 .. row]
        , check q p]
  = [ (m,n) | row <- [0..], (m,n) <- zip [row, row-1 .. 0] [0 .. row]
            , q (> m) [1 .. m + n]]
```

Now `genTree all` runs inside GHCi in near constant memory, though it is slowing down somewhat. But it got to the 3000 easily in a few seconds.

Using the top-level `treeOfNumbers`, running `filter (check all) treeOfNumbers` gets to the 3000 in 35M of memory, and about twice slower than the above.

So it's not only about the top level name;  all the interim names in your definitions cause the data retention too.

Also, do compile it with -O2 flag and run it as a standalone executable for any sizable work.

Comment: It's not naming that's the issue, specifically.  Using `reverse` is a significant issue that can be trivially avoided.  Using two comprehensions allows them both to stream.  Using `reverse` forces both lists into memory during the `zip`.

Comment: using `reverse` without the naming, `zip (reverse [0..row]) [0..row]`, would force only one of them into memory.

Comment: Yes, `reverse` is always bad for memory use. The problem is `reverse`, not named subexpressions.