# Criterion causing memory consumption to explode, no CAFs in sight

Tags: haskell, ghc

Basically I have a simple function call, which 
when used in conjunction with [Criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion), results in 
the memory consumption exploding.

Suppose I have the following program :

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-cse #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where
import Criterion.Main
import Data.List

num :: Int
num = 10000000

lst :: a -> [Int]
lst _ = [1,2..num]

myadd :: Int -> Int -> Int
myadd !x !y = let !result = x + y in
  result

mysum = foldl' myadd 0

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ mysum (lst ())
```

Then this program (compiled with O0) runs fine, without 
the memory exploding.

If we use `cabal build -v` to yield a dump of the compilation
commands invoked, and then tag `-ddump-simpl -fforce-recomp -O0 -dsuppress-all` (suggested in [IO/Monadic assign operator causing ghci to explode for infinite list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24990602)) to the end of the `ghc --make -no-link ...` command, we get the following core :

```
num
num = I# 10000000

lst
lst = \ @ a_a3Yn _ -> enumFromThenTo $fEnumInt (I# 1) (I# 2) num

myadd
myadd =
  \ x_a3Cx y_a3Cy ->
    case x_a3Cx of x1_X3CC { I# ipv_s4gX ->
    case y_a3Cy of y1_X3CE { I# ipv1_s4h0 ->
    + $fNumInt x1_X3CC y1_X3CE
    }
    }

mysum
mysum = foldl' myadd (I# 0)

main
main =
  print
    $fShowInt (mysum (enumFromThenTo $fEnumInt (I# 1) (I# 2) num))

main
main = runMainIO main
```

It seems that no CAFs are being produced, which is consistent 
with the fact that the program does not explode. Now if I 
run the following program which uses criterion 1.1.0.0 :

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-cse #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where
import Criterion.Main
import Data.List

num :: Int
num = 10000000

lst :: a -> [Int]
lst _ = [1,2..num]

myadd :: Int -> Int -> Int
myadd !x !y = let !result = x + y in
  result

mysum = foldl' myadd 0

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "summation" 
    [bench "mysum" $ whnf mysum (lst ())]
  ]
```

then the memory consumption explodes. However printing 
the core yields :

```
num
num = I# 10000000

lst
lst = \ @ a_a3UV _ -> enumFromThenTo $fEnumInt (I# 1) (I# 2) num

myadd
myadd =
  \ x_a3Cx y_a3Cy ->
    case x_a3Cx of x1_X3CC { I# ipv_s461 ->
    case y_a3Cy of y1_X3CE { I# ipv1_s464 ->
    + $fNumInt x1_X3CC y1_X3CE
    }
    }

mysum
mysum = foldl' myadd (I# 0)

main
main =
  defaultMain
    (: (bgroup
      (unpackCString# "summation"#)
      (: (bench
            (unpackCString# "mysum"#)
            (whnf mysum (enumFromThenTo $fEnumInt (I# 1) (I# 2) num)))
         ([])))
       ([]))

main
main = runMainIO main
```

and it seems that no CAFs are being produced. Therefore why
does the latter program, which uses criterion, result in the memory consumption exploding, whereas the former program 
does not? I am using GHC version 7.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your version without `criterion`, the list returned by `lst ()` gets produced lazily and then incrementally garbage collected while `mysum` consumes it, since there are no other references to the list.

For the `criterion` version, however, look at the [definition of `whnf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-1.1.0.0/docs/src/Criterion-Types.html#whnf):

```
whnf :: (a -> b) -> a -> Benchmarkable
whnf = pureFunc id
{-# INLINE whnf #-}
```

and `pureFunc`:

```
pureFunc :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> Benchmarkable
pureFunc reduce f0 x0 = Benchmarkable $ go f0 x0
  where go f x n
          | n <= 0    = return ()
          | otherwise = evaluate (reduce (f x)) >> go f x (n-1)
{-# INLINE pureFunc #-}
```

It seems like `x` in `go` above would eventually become bound to the list returned by your `lst ()`, while `n` is the number of iterations for the benchmarking.  When the first benchmark iteration is finished, `x` will all have been evaluated, but this time it cannot be garbage collected: It is still kept in memory because it is *shared* with the following iterations through the recursive `go f x (n-1)`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to inspect the source of criterion to know that `lst ()` will be shared: any subexpression will be shared (and therefore computed at most once) during the evaluation of the body of the immediately surrounding lambda. Additional lambdas may be introduced by overloading, various syntactic sugar constructs, and compiler optimizations, but none of that happens here as you can see from the Core.

If you don't want `lst ()` to be shared then you should refactor the arguments of `whnf` to something like `whnf (mysum . lst) ()`.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually tried `whnf (mysum .lst) ()` before when I was using `O3` optimization, but I found that the benchmark time was independent of `num`, so I discarded this idea. However rerunning this again with `O0` shows a clear dependence on `num`.

Comment: I asked the question about the behaviour with `O3` optimization at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340053/preventing-caching-of-computation-in-criterion-benchmark